# strange behaviour in vba macro when adding dynamic hyperlink

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've recorded a macro in word 2007 which looks like this:

```
Sub Makro1()
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
    "http://www.example.com", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:= _
    "text"
End Sub
```

In my macro, I want to set address and textToDisplay dynamically, which I tried to do by doing this simple test:

```
Sub Makro1()
Dim text1 As String
text1 = "joe"
    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
        "http://www.example.com", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:= _
        text1
End Sub
```

When I ran this macro, whole Word crashed and had to recover the document, obviously I'm doing something wrong. Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: ok I'm just commenting since this is not a solution just a hint...When I use a .value property of, for example a textbox as a Address/TextToDisplay in hyperlink. everything works as expected. So the problem is somewhere here: Dim text1 As String or text1 = "joe", I don't understand it, all fields expect string, so why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and found an answer on the [Office Development Center](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/olbasics/thread/43d727ac-3ef3-46cb-9e5d-5954ee1beb20?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/olbasics/thread/43d727ac-3ef3-46cb-9e5d-5954ee1beb20?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/olbasics/thread/43d727ac-3ef3-46cb-9e5d-5954ee1beb20)

In short, the problem is in the TextToDisplay parameter. Changing your variable type from String to Variant will work around the problem.

Dim text1 As Variant